# Google OAuth Redirect With Query String Possible?

Tags: redirect, parameters, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

Is it possible to pass a parameter to web page via the OAuth redirect URL once the user authenticates?  I have specified a parameter on the redirect URL in the Google credentials configuration page but it is not being passed.  I'd like to get the value of foo below:

```
https://example.com/Test?foo=1234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use the query parameter to encode some sort of information that will track the OAuth flow on your end.
In that case, you would need to use the **state** parameter. You will get the **state** parameter back as a parameter to your **redirect_uri**

More information:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#sendauthrequest

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#state-param

> The state can be useful for correlating requests and responses.
>   Because your redirect_uri can be guessed, using a state value can
>   increase your assurance that an incoming connection is the result of
>   an authentication request. If you generate a random string or encode
>   the hash of some client state (e.g., a cookie) in this state variable,
>   you can validate the response to additionally ensure that the request
>   and response originated in the same browser. This provides protection
>   against attacks such as cross-site request forgery.

Comment: I want to track where the sign in came from on my site as there's pages that allow for different levels of user account sign-ons such as a regular user and a service provider.  I am only using the web interface (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and set a parameter on the authorized redirect URLs from API Services credentials google page.  My next task is to integrate the API so I can validate the returned token but it appears I should be using an API call to sign-on and setting the parameters there.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Google OAuth Redirect With Query String using gem "omniauth-google-oauth2" possible?